# For Pandas whats the difference between .loc and no loc

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

When I was originally learning pandas, if I was filtering I'd use the .loc method. I've been told this is incorrect. Given the following dataframe:

```
data = {'c1':[1,2,3], 'c2':[2,3,4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=list(data.keys()))
```

you can get all values where c1 is >= 2 via *at least* these two methods:

```
df = df[df['c1']>=2]
```

or

```
df = df.loc[df['c1']>=2]
```

Which is better in what circumstances? When would you use .loc versus not?